# Ожидание загрузки диалогового окна

Tags: c#

На сайте с помощью `selenium chrome` нажимаю в браузере на кнопку добавить файлы, открывается диалоговое окно, но на разных компьютерах оно открывается с разной скоростью, как организовать ожидание этого окна без `Thread.Sleep()` ?

Comment: Так как у Selenium нет никаких эвентов, связанных с подобными событиями, то никак. Усыпляйте поток и после пробуждения проверяйте, появилось ли окно. Если нет - усыпляйте вновь и так далее

Comment: @Kir_Antipov как сделать эту проверку появления окна ? - Наверно это я и имел ввиду.